# Filter with Drop-Down Options in Python Flask App (with JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, filter

I'm trying to use drop-downs to filter results in a table. I've tried to make it work with addEventListener('click'), but I'm stuck on how to make it fully functional. I think I'm very close but missing something.

Could anyone help to provide a solution such that when the country values are clicked in the drop-down, it filters for all of those with corresponding country values in the table? This will need to work such that multiple drop-downs on multiple columns would be used.

[image]

**Python**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
test_data = [['jack', 23, 'china', 'https://www.google.com'],
             ['jill', 22, 'canada', 'https://www.cnn.com'],
             ['john', 24, 'canada', 'https://www.cnn.com'],
             ['jane', 30, 'australia', 'https://www.bbc.com']]

test_df = pd.DataFrame(test_data, columns=['name', 'age', 'country', 'link'])
test_df = test_df.to_dict(orient='index')
@app.route("/hello")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", test_df=test_df)
```

**HTML**: in an index.html

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="country">Countries</label>
    <form class="form">
        <div class="form__group">
            <select id="country" name="country" data-dropdown>
                <option value="">Please select a country</option>
                <option value="australia">Australia</option>
                <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                <option value="china">China</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <tbody id="myTable">
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript**: within the index.html in script tags

```
var mydata = JSON.parse('{{ test_df|tojson }}');
var countrySelector = document.getElementById('country');
// but what next?

buildTable(mydata)
function buildTable(data) {
    var table = document.getElementById('myTable')
    table.innerHTML = ''
    for (var key in data) {
        var row = `<tr>
                    <td>${data[key].name}</td>
                    <td>${data[key].age}</td>
                    <td><a href="${data[key].link}" target='_blank'>${data[key].country}</a></td>
               </tr>`
        table.innerHTML += row
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the select element's [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) to monitor user changes in the selection.
The following example shows you how to filter the rows by country. To make it easier to filter the rows in JavaScript, they are not passed as a dict but as a list using `df.values.tolist()`.

```
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    render_template
)
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    test_df = pd.DataFrame(
        [
            ['jack', 23, 'china', 'https://www.google.com'],
            ['jill', 22, 'canada', 'https://www.cnn.com'],
            ['john', 24, 'canada', 'https://www.cnn.com'],
            ['jane', 30, 'australia', 'https://www.bbc.com']
        ],
        columns=['name', 'age', 'country', 'link']
    )
    return render_template('index.html', test_df=test_df.values.tolist())
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <label for="country">Countries</label>
      <form class="form">
        <div class="form__group">
          <select id="country" name="country" data-dropdown>
            <option value>Please select a country</option>
            <option value="australia">Australia</option>
            <option value="canada">Canada</option>
            <option value="china">China</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>

    <table class="table">
      <tbody id="myTable">
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      function buildTable(data) {
          const table = document.getElementById('myTable')
          table.innerHTML = data.map(row => {
            let [name, age, country, link] = row;
            return `<tr>
                <td>${name}</td>
                <td>${age}</td>
                <td><a href="${link}" target='_blank'>${country}</a></td>
              </tr>`;
          }).join('');
      }

      const data = {{ test_df|tojson }};
      const countrySelector = document.getElementById('country');
      countrySelector.addEventListener('change', evt => {
        const value = evt.target.value;
        if (value) {
          buildTable(data.filter(row => {
            let [name, age, country, link] = row;
            return country === value
          }));
        } else {
          buildTable(data);
        }
      });

      buildTable(data)

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Perfect, worked like a charm. The only thing I had to add was JSON.parse and quote marks around jinja `"{{ test_df|tojson }}"`. Quick question for my learning though, is there a reason you move the test_df between the `def index():` and the `return render_template`?

Comment: The reason I moved the DataFrame to the endpoint is that I'm trying to avoid global variables. These often lead to errors and are not absolutely necessary in the example. I think the code should work without the quotes and `JSON.parse()`. A JavaScript array should be assigned to the variable `data`.